# Problem when passing argument to Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

My Makefile looks like this:

```
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.c.o)    #yes it it should be renamed to .c.o, not .o
LIBS = -lchecl -lchecs -lchengine-dev -lglfw -lm -lGL -lGLEW -lcheio -lopenal -lfreetype
EXE = test
VER = -std=c99
MODE = -g
OPT = -O0 
ERR = -Wall -Wuninitialized -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=int-conversion -Wduplicated-cond -Wlogical-op -Wrestrict -Wnull-dereference -Wjump-misses-init -Wdouble-promotion -Wshadow -Wformat=2
LFLAGS = -o
CFLAGS = $(ERR) $(VER) $(OPT) -c $(MODE) `pkg-config --cflags freetype2`

run: $(EXE)
    ./$(EXE)


$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    gcc $(LFLAGS) $(EXE) $(OBJ) $(LIBS)

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $(CFLAGS) $*.c
    mv "$$(basename $*.o)" "$$(dirname $*)"

cleanall:
    rm $(OBJ)
    rm $(SRC)
```

And I am passing the `SRC` variable like this:

```
files=$(find . -type f -name '*.c.c')
make run SRC="$files"
```

But this gives the the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'src/setup.c
./states/mainMenuState.c
...
(a list of all source files)'
```

However if I manually copy the value of `$files` into the Makefile, writing `SRC =`  and then the source files, it compiles just fine. If I write instead of `OBJ = $(SRC:.c.c=.c.o)`  `OBJ = $($(SRC):.c.c=.c.o)` it seems to compile but not link correctly, because then I get this error:

```
//usr/local/lib/libchengine-dev.so: undefined reference to `vector_find'
//usr/local/lib/libchengine-dev.so: undefined reference to `che_init'
//usr/local/lib/libchengine-dev.so: undefined reference to `vector_destruct'
```

Comment: What you show is not sufficient to understand where your problem comes from. Your Makefile does not use `SRC` (except in the `clean` recipe), we do not know which source files you have, where they are, where you want to build your object files, etc. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Just to point out (this is not related to your question) you convert your source files to object files with the suffix `.c.o` but your pattern rule: `%.o : %.c` won't match that and won't be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SRC` is used in the definition of `OBJ`.  But this can't be your real makefile, because it won't work.  So something must be different about your real makefile versus what you've shown us, and that difference is critical to the problem you're having.  As Renaud says, please provide a MCVE.

I created a simple makefile:

```
OBJS := $(SRC:.c=.c.o)

all: $(OBJS)

%.c.o : %.c
        : $< $@
```

then ran it:

```
files=$(find -name \*.c)
make SRC="$files"
```

and it worked just fine:

```
: foo.c foo.c.o
: bar.c bar.c.o
: biz.c biz.c.o
: baz.c baz.c.o
```

You can work around the problem in GNU make 4.1 by not including newlines in the `$files` variable.  For example you can change how you set it to this:

```
files=$(find . -type f -name '*.c.c' -printf '%p ')
```

so it uses space separators instead of newlines.

Comment: No, a script creates files that are named e.g. foo.c.c and bar.c.c .These files should then be compiled into bar.c.o files

Comment: Thanks for editing your example.  However, if you truly get this error with that exact makefile, I can't explain it because it works fine for me.  What version of make are you using?  What operating system are you using?

Comment: Regarding your link error: that likely means that your libraries are listed in an incorrect order.  Most likely you need to put `-lchengine-dev` first on the link line, but the only way to know for sure is to figure out which library supplies the missing symbols.  Remember most linkers use "single-pass" so you need to order them as "most general" to "most specific".

Comment: GNU Make 4.1, Ubuntu 18

Comment: Using GNU make 4.1 I get the same behavior as you.  Using GNU make 4.2 or above, it works as I show in my answer.  GNU make 4.2 was released in May 2016.